# SOAP UI Tests are running long time from jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, ant, soapui

I am trying to integrate my Jenkins with **SOAP** UI through Ant.

Below is my build.xml file.

```
<project name="RegressionTests" default="soapui-tests" basedir=".">
    <description>Run the soapUI Regression Tests</description>
    <!-- <property file="build.properties"/> -->
    <property name="soapUITest.home" value="C:\Regression_Test"/>
    <property name="SOAP_UI_PROJ_FILE" value="${SOAP_UI_PROJ_FILE}" />
    <property name="SOAP_UI_TEST_SUITE" value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_SUITE}" />
    <property name="SOAP_UI_TEST_CASE" value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_CASE}" />
    <property name="SOAP_UI_TEST_REPORT" value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_REPORT}" />

    <target name="checkos">
        <condition property="testrunner.cmd" value="${soapUITest.home}\bin\testrunner.bat">
                <os family="windows" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="soapui-tests" depends="checkos">
        <exec executable="${testrunner.cmd}"
              failonerror="yes"
              failifexecutionfails="yes" >
            <arg value="${SOAP_UI_PROJ_FILE}"/>
            <arg value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_SUITE}"/>
            <arg value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_CASE}"/>
             <arg value="${SOAP_UI_TEST_REPORT}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

Now testrunner.bat calls **SOAPUI** testrunner batch file.

```
@echo off

set SOAP_UI_PROJ_FILE=%1
set SOAP_UI_TEST_SUITE=%2
set SOAP_UI_TEST_CASE=%3
set SOAP_UI_TEST_REPORT=%4

@echo off

set RESOURCE_HOME="C:\Regression_Test\resources"
set SOAP_UI_RESOURCE_FILE="%RESOURCE_HOME%/%SOAP_UI_PROJ_FILE%"

"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat" -s%SOAP_UI_TEST_SUITE%  -c%SOAP_UI_TEST_CASE% -r -a -f"%SOAP_UI_TEST_REPORT%" %SOAP_UI_RESOURCE_FILE%
```

While I try to run from Jenkins
I see below SOAP UI is running for indefinite time but no error
[Jenkins Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLrC4.jpg)

I ran the same from command line argument and completed within seconds.

Can anyone suggest why the **SOAPUI** tests are running indefinitely in Jenkins

Thanks,
Ayan Bhattacharyya

Comment: try to run the test only from the batch using Jenkins "execute windows batch command" and see what happens

Comment: Can you first try to run it thru ant using command line and update your findings? If there any thing suspicious, try to run ant script in debug mode and see what is causing this to get delayed. Jenkins can be the next step.

Comment: Hello @ShacharHamuzimRajuan, I can run the batch file using command line and complete within seconds. But even if I ran the same batch file through Jenkins using command line it never complete. I suspect issue is not with ant or batch file but may be something with Jenkins in windows server . Suprisingly, I have another Jenkins instance in unix server. I tried to run testrunner.sh in unix server using same SOAP Project. Worked fine. But I need to implement in Windows, as I also have dragonfly integrated with SOAP UI to upload results in HPALM. Unfortunately dragonfly do not work in Unix

Comment: Hello @Rao, When I ran ant in debug mode, I see SOAP UI Test Cases ran successfully, command: ant -d -buildfile "C:\Regression_Test\bin\build.xml"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check where the soapui-settings is being loaded from. When I ran from Jenkins, it was looking at C:\soapui-settings.xml which does not exist, as compared to running from the command prompt which was pointing to the correct file. After copying soapui-settings.xml to the C:\ drive, the Jenkins build completed successfully. Hope this helps.

11:42:45,088 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\soapui-settings.xml]